# Selecting a Range of Adjacent Columns for Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am not understanding how to essentially say: `columns= [0:6, 12:15])`

When I try this I get invalid syntax at the `:`

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (rf'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export.xlsx',
                       sheet_name=1,
                       header=None)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  columns= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,12,13,14,15])

df.to_csv(rf'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export1.csv',
          header=False,
          index=False)  

print (df)
```

Comment: You can write `columns=range(7)`

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to select columns (1:4, 12:20) ?

Answer (score 0):

this thing that you trying is slicing. it used for select a subset of a list
You can use the `range` function for create numbers and convert it to a list with the `list` function

```
list(range(0,6+1)) + list(range(12,15+1))
```

```
#output :
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```